# Registering DNS Records

Tags: dns

I am trying to add/update DNS records at every X sec to my custom dns server which is located in another device.
I have seen implementations that send custom UDP messages (for DNS registery) to do that but is there any other way to accomplish this with services/daemons.
I looked over dhclient, systemd-resolve, dnsmasq but I couldn't find a way to accomplish what I want. I think they are for implementing DNS server not client, am I wrong, what am I missing?
Should I register these DNS records with UDP packages instead of letting linux do the job for me? What is the right way for this?

Comment: What software is the "custom" DNS server? Does it support dynamic DNS updates? Dynamic DNS update protocol is specified in RFC 2136. You need a server and client that supports it. The "golden standard" in DNS server software, BIND, does support dynamic updates if configured appropriately. To send dynamic DNS updates to the server, a program called `nsupdate` is used.

Comment: @raj Yes it does support DDNS, thank you for your advice I will look it up.